# Can Blazor Server App have nested routes?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have used authentication (`AuthenticationStateProvider`) in my Blazor Sever App. I have `login`, `user`, and `admin` pages. Is it possible to use nested routes in Blazor and access it directly through address bar of the browser? For example, I want to use the following routes:

1. https://localhost:7282/admin/info/userslist
2. https://localhost:7282/user/register/personalinfo

Comment: No offense, but 5 or 10 hours with some YouTube videos would see you well on your way to understanding Blazor.  Also this: https://blazor-university.com/, and in this case specifically https://blazor-university.com/routing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most certainly can use routing, as @titol shows.  However, I generally use routing only for main pages, and use logic to display sub-pages as components.  I've never used a page route longer than 2 levels.

```
@page "admin/info"

@switch (InfoPage){
    case InfoPages.Contact:
        <MyContactComponent/>;
    case InfoPages.Map:
        <MyMapComponent/>;
    case InfoPages.UserSettings:
        <MyUserSettingsComponent />
}

@code{
    public enum InfoPages { Contact, Map, UserSettings }

    [Parameter] 
    public InfoPages InfoPage {get; set;} = InfoPages.Contact;
}
```

This way, you can use whatever mechanism you want to swap the components: a json-formatted instruction from an AI bot, a search bar, a button, a dropdown, etc.  Just set `InfoPage` to a new value.

Comment: The problem is that when I use more than one level of route, all the css and js file addresses are change (For example: https://localhost:7282/admin/_framework/blazor.server.js). This causes 404 error.

Comment: The problem solved. I had deleted `<base href="~/" />` accidently.  I added it and the problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is.
It doesn't matter if you are using `AuthenticationStateProvider` or not.
I believe you should start with some reading about routes directly in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Using routes from your question, you need to put it directly in any razor component like this:

```cs
@page "/admin/info/userslist"

<h1>This is admin route </h1>
```

or

```cs
@page "/user/register/personalinfo"

<h1>This is admin user route</h1>
```